# ROS Answers SE migration: rospack error

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have ubuntu LTS 12.04 and I work on groovy. I tried to build my package with rosmake and then, I have this:

```
mkdir -p bin 
cd build && cmake -Wdev
-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/opt/ros/groovy/share/ros/core/rosbuild/rostoolchain.cmake  .. 
[rosbuild] Building package lwr_fri 
Failed to invoke /opt/ros/groovy/bin/rospack deps-manifests lwr_fri 
[rospack] Error: package/stack 'lwr_fri' depends on non-existent package 'kuka_lwr_fri' and rosdep claims that it is not a system dependency. Check the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH or try calling 'rosdep update' 


CMake Error at /opt/ros/groovy/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:129 (message): 


Failed to invoke rospack to get compile flags for package 'lwr_fri'.  Look 
above for errors from rospack itself.  Aborting.  Please fix the broken 
dependency! 

Call Stack (most recent call first): 
/opt/ros/groovy/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:203 (rosbuild_invoke_rospack) 
CMakeLists.txt:25 (rosbuild_init) 



-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

For solve the problem, I tried to write this command:

```
sudo rm -r /opt/ros/groovy/bin/rospack
```

And it works but I'm not sure if it's a good solution ..

I would like to have some opinions about this, please.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/103526/rospack-error/) by [alivero](https://answers.ros.org/users/8946/alivero/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-11-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That is not a good solution.

Your error is that you're missing a dependency. Your fix is to remove a tool which enables detecting the missing dependency.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-10-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0